# Sending information from webhook to views.py Django

Tags: django, django-views, webhooks

I am developing my first Django website and I have the following scenario.

I get user input, then I make a call to an external API in the backend and I receive something using a webhook. Here, I need to send a 200 response to the API.
But I also need to return something to the user, after processing what I get in the webhook.

My question is how do I implement this inside my views.py? Making my views wait for the webhook to be triggered and then return a response to the user?

Comment: “This is called Invariance and Covariance. If you Google it, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.” Or provide more details for a more specific question

Comment: It's not about that, but I found an already answered similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59352512/how-do-i-notify-the-user-about-a-webhook-in-django