# Implement webhook in Django

Tags: django, notifications, webhooks

I have never implemented a webhook before. I am working on a payment confirmation, where I need to know if a payment is successful and if it is the client should be redirected to payment complete site. Below is the view for the checkout page.

Note the view is a GET and not a POST because during the payment process the client will be using a third party payment app to process the payment, and once the payment is processed the 3rd party app will somehow call the Payment view again. Using a post view I run into an error

> This web page requires data that you entered earlier in order to be
> properly displayed. You can send this data again, but by doing so you
> will repeat any action this page previously performed. Press the
> reload button to resubmit the data needed to load the page
> ERR_CACHE_MISS

```
class Payment(View):
    def __init__(self):
        #Get model webshopRestaurant data for hd2900 restaurant for location id for this restaurant
        self.hd2900RestaurantObject = RestaurantUtils(restaurantName = restaurantName)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #Check if session is still valid 
        sessionValid = webshopUtils.checkSessionIdValidity(request = request, session_id_key = session_id_key, validPeriodInDays = self.hd2900RestaurantObject.restaurantModelData.session_valid_time)
        
        #In this case the session has expired and the user will be redirected
        if sessionValid is False:
            return redirect('hd2900_takeaway_webshop')
        
        if 'pickupForm' in request.GET:
            deliveryType ='pickup'
        elif 'deliveryForm' in request.GET:
            deliveryType = 'delivery'
        elif ('deliveryForm' not in request.GET) and ('pickupForm' not in request.GET):
            #Here is where I need to implement the webhook
            pass

        #Write the customer info into the data base
        webshopUtils.create_or_update_Order(session_id_key=session_id_key, request=request, deliveryType = deliveryType)

        #Calculate the total price followed by creation of paymentID from NETS
        if 'pickupForm' in request.GET:
            totalPrice = webshopUtils.get_BasketTotalPrice(request.session[session_id_key]) + self.hd2900RestaurantObject.restaurantModelData.bagFee
        elif 'deliveryForm' in request.GET:
            totalPrice = webshopUtils.get_BasketTotalPrice(request.session[session_id_key]) + self.hd2900RestaurantObject.restaurantModelData.delivery_fee + self.hd2900RestaurantObject.restaurantModelData.bagFee

        #Create an order reference and link that to NETS reference
        reference = webshopUtils.get_order_reference(request = request, session_id_key=session_id_key)

        #Get the payment id from NETS 
        payment = NETS()
        paymentId = payment.get_paymentId(platform = platform,
        reference = reference, 
        name = 'Hidden Dimsum 2900 Takeaway',
        paymentReference = session_id_key,
        unitPrice = int(totalPrice) *100)

        if paymentId.status_code == 201:
            paymentId = paymentId.json()['paymentId']

        #Put the checkout key and the payment id into the page that javascript is going to read from during payment
        checkoutKey = payment.getCheckoutKey(platform = platform)

        context = dict()
        context['paymentId'] = paymentId
        context['checkoutKey'] = checkoutKey

        return render(request, template_name="takeawayWebshop/webshopPayment.html", context = context)
```

In the elif statement in the above code is where I need to listen to the webhook to see if the payment has been successful. From this [documentation](https://tech.dibspayment.com/easy/api/paymentapi#getPayment) under create payment section it is possible to add a webhook (in notification key) upon requesting for a payment id, but I have no idea how to implement this in Django. The documentation snippet says

> notifications - Used to get the status of a transaction (optional)
> webhooks - List of webhooks the merchant wants to register for the
> payment. Maximum number of webhooks is 32. eventName - Input the event
> you want to listen for url - The callback is sent to this url on the
> merchant site. Must be https. Maximum length is 256 characters.
> authorization - Header of the callback sent to the merchant site will
> be set to this value. Must be between 8 and 32 characters long and
> alphanumeric.

This post is very similar to the problem from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59352512/how-do-i-notify-the-user-about-a-webhook-in-django), but after studying the problem I am still unsure how to implement it. Especially I don't really know how a webhook work. Is it like a get request where I constantly need to call for it? How should I form the url in the webhook so that I know that this url is for this specific payment session?

At last it is important for me to add the reason why I need to listen to the webhook in the first place. In the payment integration after obtained the payment id I am using the javascript below to render the payment form embedded in my page. When payment is completed it will redirect to '/paymentComplete' url. The problem here is during the payment if the user reload the page then the get method will be called again, and in such a case the javascript below will no longer work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Get payment id from server
    var paymentId = document.getElementById("paymentId").innerHTML.trim();
    var checkoutKey = document.getElementById("checkoutKey").innerHTML.trim();

    const checkoutOptions = {
        checkoutKey: checkoutKey,
        paymentId: paymentId,
        containerId: "checkout-container-div",
        };
        
        const checkout = new Dibs.Checkout(checkoutOptions)
        checkout.on('payment-completed', function (response) {
            window.location = '/paymentComplete';
        });
});
```

Comment: Two things, 1. This view changes stuff (`writes`, `creates` and `updates` are in your comments) so this view should probably be a POST endpoint

Comment: 2. Webhooks are callback urls, meaning the 3rd party will call the url you have set up as the webhook when they are finished doing their processes, but that will not reflect on the current user's session since the 3rd party will call the webhook url outside of the user's session. So you have to have a mechanism for your front-end to "poll" your backend about the results of a webhook processing, or just wait for the user to refresh the page for updated status.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. 1) I have edited the question to explain why I used a GET and not a POST view. 2) You have no idea how much this one helped me. It seems like the strategy should be to redirect the client to a waiting page while client's front end is calling my backend for webhook result every 5 sec. If the payment is confirmed the client is redirected to payment confirmation page. How do I setup a webhook listener in Django? I guess I need a way to create uniqueness in the webhook url to link the url to this unique payment session?

Comment: Usually webhooks are just generic urls. Say for example if you use paypal as a payment 3rd party, you can tell paypal to use this url as the webhook: `yoursite.com/api/v1/paypal/webhook`. When paypal hits that view after some time, it should tell you which payment it has processed, which should then reflect on your database for example. So your waiting page can check for updates on a specific payment from another view that gets the details for that payment, taken from your DB. This is just an example but that's the essence

Comment: Keep in mind that webhooks will usually come with some security implementation you need to implement so don't forget that. Otherwise anyone can use your webhook url to manipulate your data. In your example it's the authorization/headers